# parse Issue "Expected a type" error occur in framework

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, frameworks, parse-platform

I am using "parse.com" in my application. I just bought a new system and i want to shift my project in new mac but in new mac my project makes issue of "Parse Issue" and error "Expected a type". While on my old system it is working really fine.

These errors are coming in my frame work "Parse.framework" and file "PFFacebookUtils.h".
I clean my project and build I quit my xcode then build but in vain. Kindly help me to run it on new system. Pic is attached also and if someone wants me to upload code then kindly tell me
[image]

Comment: Did you tried to delete the framework and download it again?

Comment: Yes i tried it but in vain

Comment: Error is occuring in "PFFacebookUtils.h" (a framework file) I removed the Parse.framework and then build again but still it is giving error in the same file. I don't know why it still have the reference of file

Answer (score 0):

In your projects build phases make sure that your framework is listed under link binaries

Answer (score 0):

I got fixed my problem. It was really weird problem for as it is a generic error. It was not showing any clue. My problem is fixed when i just added the latest version of facebookSDK in my documents folder.